# Create a jquery plugin which uses autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, jquery-widgets

I am trying to build a jquery plugin for my website which uses autocomplete to fillout a text box. 
I am trying to call it as:

```
$("#txtBox").suggest()
```

from my HTML page. These are my references.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Suggest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/Trial/test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("txtBox").suggest();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Enter a Symbol:</p><br />
    <input type = "text" id = "txtBox" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my plugin test.js:

```
(function ($) {        
    $.fn.suggest = function () {

    //Autocomplete not found!    
    this.autocomplete ({
        source: //Some source
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
}(jQuery));
```

It says autocomplete is undefined. Can anyone help?

Comment: In your case this is just the scope of the function it is executed in. I suggest reading about the jQuery automplete http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: do you want something from the response to be populated in autocomplete?

Comment: No, the request is made to get a secure token which will be used in autocomplete. Here, another request would be made which would populate my data. I have a working piece of code where autocomplete can me used as inline script. It is failing when I try to use it as a plugin